# Error UTF-8 pod install & Phared Preferences iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I run `pod install`

Terminal in Android Studio return

```
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.

Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I have error when install package **Share Preferences**

I run projects by Mac Terminal get

```
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/mac/Desktop/app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal
error: module 'shared_preferences_ios' not found
@import shared_preferences_ios;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly
because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select
a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project
'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (cmd+space).

enter this line:-

[image]

~> sudo gem install cocoapods

for more information about cocoapods visit:-

[click here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html)